# Reverse string realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I have created this small program to reverse a sentence.
So given: a b c d

It will give: d c b a

This works fine, until I add an extra letter. If I try "a b c d e" it will fail at the last one with the error

realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000602010 ***

Here is the code

```
#define MAX_TEXT 100

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <stdlib.h> //realloc


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char text[MAX_TEXT] = { 0 };    
    char *parts = NULL;

    printf("Insert string: ");
    fgets(text,MAX_TEXT,stdin);
    sscanf(text,"%[^\n]",text); //remove the \n


    char **reverse = NULL;
    char **extra = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;

    parts = strtok (text," ");
    while (parts != NULL) {

        size += ((strlen(parts)+4) * sizeof(char));
        extra = realloc(reverse,size);

        if (extra) {
            reverse = extra; 
            reverse[i++] = parts;
        }     
        else {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        parts = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    while (--i >= 0) {
        printf("%s ",reverse[i]);                
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I am still newbish with using pointers let alone pointer to pointer, so any help will be great.
Thanks!

Ps: I tried using valgrind and it just points that there is something wrong at the realloc but I can't understand what exactly.

UPDATED CODE:

```
#define MAX_TEXT 500

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //strchr
#include <stdlib.h> //realloc


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char text[MAX_TEXT] = { 0 };        

    printf("Insert string: ");
    fgets(text,MAX_TEXT,stdin);
    //sscanf(text,"%[^\n]",text); //remove the \n <-- Undefined behaviour :D "if copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."
    char *theEnter = strchr(text,'\n');
    if (theEnter) {
        *theEnter = 0;//remove \n
    }        

    char **reverse = NULL;
    char **extra = NULL;
    char *parts = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    size_t increse_by = sizeof(char *);

    parts = strtok (text," ");
    while (parts != NULL) {

        size += increse_by; //pointer to pointer so increase by the size of new pointer
        extra = realloc(reverse,size);

        if (extra) {
            reverse = extra; 
            reverse[i++] = parts;
        }     
        else {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        parts = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    while (--i >= 0) {
        printf("%s ",reverse[i]);                
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Following Charlie Burns indication I am now allocating for char *, I also removed the sscanf function and used strchr to remove \n because, as chux indicated, what I was doing was undefined behavior.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Working fine. check this link http://ideone.com/ly8ws2

Comment: That means nothing.  The OP is getting undefined behavior

Comment: OP is allocating space for the char* and the strings themselves when he really should be allocating just for the char* array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your realloc is not allocating enough space. sizeof(char *) is probably 8 on your machine.
Your realloc below will allocate (1 + 4) * 1 = 5 for a parts of strlen == 1. That's not enough for the string pointer.

Try changing

```
    size += ((strlen(parts)+4) * sizeof(char));
```

to

```
    size += sizeof(char *);
```

Reason being that `extra` and `reverse` are char **. So they are an array of pointers to strings. This array gets one bigger with each loop through `strtok`(). `strtok`() returns a null terminated string. So you don't need to alloc memory for that.

You don't need to in this case, but you could also do:

```
reverse[i++] = strdup(parts);
```

If you wanted to the strings in `reverse` to point to copies of the strings in `text`, not inside `text` itself.

Comment: Any thoughts on `sscanf(text,"%[^\n]",text)`?  Either it is novel or UB.  I'm _thinking it is UB because of `restrict` in `int sscanf(const char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...)`.

Comment: @chux, I am really really old school have not kept up with recent changes including restrict. So I can't intelligently comment on that. If restrict means the pointers are not supposed to overlap, then I think you have a point.

Comment: @chux, your question is good, you should ask on, say, StackOverflow and see what folks have to say.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Right! It a pointer to pointer so I should increase by a char pointer and not a char. Thanks :)

Comment: @chux I have removed the sscanf and instead used strchr to find the \n and replace it with 0 Thanks :)

Comment: @AntonioCS I assume the `strchr()` change is not in an update of your post as I do not see it, but on your local machine.

Comment: @chux Yes. I will update the post :)